# Is there anyway to search PL/SQL reserved words with contains function?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there anyway to search PL/SQL reserved words with the `contains` function in the Oracle?

We would like to search keywords such as "test for" or "test do" with the `contains` or `catsearch` functions from the user table in Oracle but the results only show for "test" and ignore those reserved words such as "do" or "for" automatically.

We assume we have a table called content in the users schema.

[image]

The queries are listed below:

```
create table users.content (content_id int not null, content varchar(20) not null);

insert into users.content values (1, 'do something');

insert into users.content values (2, 'test it');

insert into users.content values (3, 'it has been tested');

insert into users.content values (4, 'will test it');

create index users.idx_content on users.content (content) indextype is ctxsys.context;

--drop index users.idx_content;

--drop table users.content;

select content_id, content from users.content where contains(content, 'do or test') > 0;
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Colin'tHart we would like to search keywords such as "for test" or "do test" with contains or catsearch function in the Oracle but the results only show for "test" and ignore the reserved words such as "do" or "for" etc.

Comment: Are you trying to search the text of code stored in Oracle (which is what I initially read your question as asking)?  Or are you trying to search for data stored in a user-defined table?  If you're searching for data in a user-defined table, can you create an Oracle Text index on that table?

Comment: @Justin Cave I am trying to search data from user-defined table and have created the index for that table already. the contains function is working fine with all of keywords except Oracle reserved words.

Comment: What do you consider "Oracle reserved words"?  "do", for example, is not a reserved word in `v$reserved_words`.

Comment: @Justin Cave So "do" should be working for this case....I think it is PL/SQL reserved word and "for" is either PL/SQL or SQL reserved word.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `contains` because there is no Oracle Text index on the database source.  You could, I suppose, write a query that copied the data from `dba_source` to a custom table, create an Oracle Text index on that table, and search that table using the `contains` function.

It would generally make more sense, though, to just query `dba_source` with a `like` query

```
SELECT *
  FROM dba_source
 WHERE lower( text ) like '%for %';
```

Comment: Sorry, I should explain clearly. we want to search keywords such as "for test" or "do test" with contains or catsearch function from user table in the Oracle but the results only show for "test" and ignore the "for" or "do" etc. Thanks.

Comment: @Andy - Sorry, I'm afraid that comment doesn't clarify anything for me.  It may be useful to expand your question to include, say, a few example pieces of code, the types of searches you want to run, and the expected results of those searches on that sample code.  Neither "for test" or "do test" are keywords in PL/SQL-- "for" is a keyword but neither "do" nor "test" are.

Comment: I modified the question and you can have a look. However, thank you for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The following post answers my question and we ignored the stoplist when we created the indexes.

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2181803